# How to use jQuery selector with variables and other parameters

Tags: jquery, variables, serialization, parameters, selector

I am new to jQuery and really confused with this situation.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    var divId = 'intro';
    alert($('#intro :input').serialize()); -- works
    alert($('#divId :input').serialize()); -- does not work !!
  });
});
```

Can you please help me to use the variable for the div id in the serialize method?

Answer (score -1):

You have to treat the selector as a string:

```
alert($('#' + divId + ' :input').serialize());
```